# Weird error on Table Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

So I built this fairly large table layout xml file. The view in the Graphical Layout looks perfect but in the code view the entire thing is underlined in orange with the error

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>       - Element type "Button" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/
>   ".
>       - No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document.

Now all of my buttons are properly labeled and the document has a XML schema, so what could be wrong?

ps. Also when I go to save it, the console outputs "Error in an XML file:aborting build"

Here is my code:
    http://pastebin.com/42GMBmvv

Comment: If you post your layout xml someone will be able to point the problem to you.

Comment: can you post the xml file to pastebin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add space from the second bulk of buttons until the end:

```
<Button android:text="" android:id="@+id/x0y1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.16"></Button>
                                                                                                                  here ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice how you have:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:layout_weight="0.16"
```

from the second row onward for your buttons, you need a "space" between the attributes, like in your first table row buttons:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.16"
```

Cheers